# Table not getting created under dbo schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When creating tables in SSMS, I've realized that if you execute the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [tableName];
```

the table will be created under your own schema (and not dbo).  So in order to create it under the dbo schema, you'll need to explicitly say so, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableName];
```

Does anyone know of a way (eg. server-wide setting) so that when a table is created, the [dbo] part doesn't need to be specified?

Comment: Which version of SQL server?

Comment: And why do you have a problem with explicitly specifying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL 2008 R2 creates user/schema when Windows user creates tables](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/sql-2008-r2-creates-user-schema-when-windows-user-creates-tables). And related http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7254/630

Answer (score 10):

The schema that will be used when schema is omitted will be the default schema of the database user.  Therefore, to have `dbo` schema have the created table without specifying, you'd have to set that database user's default schema to `dbo`.

Server-wide setting?  I don't think so.  But you could write a query to convert all database users in a particular database to their default schema changed to `dbo` if that's what you so choose.

Comment: @KAJ: SQL2008R2

Comment: But you can't set the default schema to dbo for Windows groups...

Comment: @Chinesinho You can't set the default schema of any server principal.  You're confusing server logins and database users.  Database users contain default schemas.

Comment: Setting the default schema for users mapped to Windows group logins isn't supported prior to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this can help

```
USE [YourDBName]
GO
ALTER USER [YourUserName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Comment: but if user is in windows Authentication then it cannot set the default schema